# Filtering array inside object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to filter an array inside the object and return a new array that matches the filter

```
const example = [ { id: 1, b: [1, 2]}, {id:2, b:[1]}, {id 3, b: [1,3]}
const filter = 1
```

the return of the filter should just be `[{id: 2, b:[1]}]`

Comment: Which object do you want to filter? `1` is `index` or `data` inside an array.

Comment: data and i want to filter example.b

Comment: Still not clear, Please be specific and clear what exactly do you want? Do you want all the objects in `example` array to be filtered, which will only contain `1` inside.

Comment: Since `1` is in all objects, so there must be criteria, how you wanna filter out the array.

Comment: yes that's it..

Comment: So currently I used includes() but it will return all of the three object since it is in all of them but the expected out is the object that only contains 1 inside the array

Comment: You can check its `length` which should be `1` and if it includes `1` then it is the result that you are looking for. Simple

Answer (score 0):

**1)** If you only want an object that only contain `1` inside it. then you can it using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) do as:

```
o.b.length === 1 && o.b[0] === filter
```

```js
const example = [
  { id: 1, b: [1, 2] },
  { id: 2, b: [1] },
  { id: 3, b: [1, 3] },
];
const filter = 1;

const result = example.filter((o) => o.b.length === 1 && o.b[0] === filter);
console.log(result);
```

**2)** Using [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const example = [
  { id: 1, b: [1, 2] },
  { id: 2, b: [1] },
  { id: 3, b: [1, 3] },
];
const filter = 1;

const result = example.filter((o) => o.b.length === 1 && o.b.includes(filter));
console.log(result);
```